# Equivalent of IC4026

Tags: digital-logic

I have tried to make a reaction timer using IC 4026. But due to unavailability of IC 4026 I want to replace it. Can I use 4017 instead of 4026?[image: rection timer]

Comment: If you're not in a desperate rush on e-bay if you search on CD4026 you can get them for a few dollars with free postage and places like Digikey have them (although postage will be more).

Comment: I don't know why you're having trouble finding 4026 parts. [TI Still manufacture them](http://www.ti.com/product/CD4026B?keyMatch=cd4026&tisearch=Search-EN), and they're [in stock on digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/logic-counters-dividers/2556429?k=4026).

Answer (score 5):

In a word; no.

The 4017 is a decade counter with decoded one-hot outputs, while the 4026 is a decade counter with decoded 7-segment outputs.

Here are the data sheets for the [4017](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4017b.pdf) and the [4026](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4026b.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

Although the 4017 is not an equivalent to the 4026 you **can** use a 4017 if you build your own 7-segment encoder, e.g. as [diode matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_matrix):

[image]